# Get Object Class from WebServices to Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I got a problem when receive object from webservices to asp.net.
My problem must not to use AddWebReference.It mustn't use in my project.
Because user have to input information about webservices such as: IPAddress,Port.
Then,Client will use this information for access to Webservices.

It's function at Webservices:

```
 [SoapRpcMethod("", RequestNamespace = "urn:ALBAPI", ResponseNamespace = "urn:ALBAPI")]
        public ResponseInfo getAdvCertExport(out AdvCertExportValues values);
        public void getAdvCertExportAsync();
        public void getAdvCertExportAsync(object userState);
```

Client:

```
public void call()
        {
            string WebserviceUrl = "http://192.168.2.19:3333/ALBAPI.wsdl";
            string serviceName = "ALBAPI";
            string methodName = "getSetupLicenseRows";
            object[] args=new object[1];
            object sSessionID = CallWebService(WebserviceUrl, serviceName, methodName,args);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in sSessionID.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(sSessionID, null);

                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, value);
            }

        }

        public object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            //-Connect To the web service
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl"))
            {
                //--Now read the WSDL file describing a service.
                ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
                ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////
                //--Initialize a service description importer.
                ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
                importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.
                importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
                //--Generate a proxy client. importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
                //--Generate properties to represent primitive values.
                importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
                //--Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
                CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
                CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
                unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
                //--Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code
                //--that uses the service.
                ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
                if (warning == 0) //--If zero then we are good to go
                {
                    //--Generate the proxy code 
                    CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
                    //--Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references
                    string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
                    CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
                    CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
                    //-Check For Errors
                    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine("========Compiler error============");
                            sb.AppendLine(oops.ErrorText);
                        }
                        throw new System.ApplicationException("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. " + sb.ToString());
                    }
                    //--Finally, Invoke the web service method 
                    Type foundType = null;
                    Type[] types = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes();
                    foreach (Type type in types)
                    {
                        if (type.BaseType == typeof(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
                            foundType = type;
                        }
                    }

                    object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(foundType.ToString());
                    MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod("getSetupLicenseRows");
                    object o = new object();                    
                    Line 100:o = mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);
                    return o;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

It show error."Parameter count mismatch." at Line 100:o = mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);
Thanks in advance for your helping by anyway.

Comment: Compile time or runtime error?

Comment: if you are working with ASMX web services, it might serve you better to just set the URL to dynamic in the WebReference. Then you can pass in any url you want: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: @Hardrada: Thanks for your suggestion.But I mustn't use AddWebReference in this project.Must use codebehind for access webservices